# Finding title of webpage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Suppose I have this AJAX code in my Chrome extension

```js
//bind to all links
$('a').click( function() {
   //get the url
   var url = $(this).prop('href');
   //send the url to your server
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://yourserver.com/process.php",
        data: "url=" + url
   });
});
```

Now, I want to send not only the URL, but also the title of the page (as specified in the HTML `<title>` tag.) How can I get that title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `document.title`:

```js
//bind to all links
$('a').click( function() {
   //get the url
   var url = $(this).prop('href');
   var title = document.title;
   //send the url to your server
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://yourserver.com/process.php",
        // Haven't tested this yet :)
        data: '{"url": "' + url + '", "title": "' + title + '"}';
   });
});
```